# Under what cirumstances would I need eruby if I'm just doing Ruby programming

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, eruby

As I understand it, eruby is like erb - it lets you stick ruby code into HTML. If someone is using Rails, more than likely they would use erb or Haml.

**But if I'm not using Rails, under what cirumstances would I need eruby if I'm just doing Ruby programming?**

I guess I don't understand why someone would need to be outputting HTML if they're just using Ruby for writing scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eRuby isn't just for HTML - it allows you to embed ruby into any arbitrary text.  I've seen it used in scripts that generate Apache configuration files, for instance - it's generally useful if you have any sort of text-based output that needs some dynamic content, as an eRuby template can often be easier to read than a bunch of string concatenation or interpolation.

Comment: +1 It's a general templating language. Generating HTML is where it's usually employed, but they're not married or anything.

Answer (score 0):

You just answered your own question. If your script needs to output HTML, you could use eruby. Other than that, you probably don't need it.